# difference between intt *p=a and int *p1=&a

Tags: c, pointers

Let `a` be an array. `a[] = {1,2,3,4,5}`

```
int *p=a+1;  
int *p1=&a+1;  
printf("%d\n%d",*(p-1),*(p1-1));
```

why output of the above is:

```
1  
5
```

What is the difference between `int *p = a` and `int *p1 = &a`?

Comment: What is the full type of a?  Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which compiles.

Comment: That wouldn't print `1` or `5` unless you added some `*` to dereference the result of `p - 1` and `p1 - 1`.

Comment: `int *p1=&a+1;` is an error. If you don't see an error message then adjust compiler settings.

Answer (score 1):

In `a + 1`, `a` degrades to a pointer to its first element (an `int*`), then adding one gets a pointer to `a[1]` because it adjusts the pointer by the size of what it points to (an `int`).

In `&a + 1`, `&a` gets a pointer to *all* of `a`; it's an `int(*)[5]` (that is, a pointer to an array of five `int`s) beginning at the same address as `a[0]`, and adding `1` adjusts the pointer by the size of what it points to (moving it along by five `int`s), making it effectively point to `a[5]`; it then degrades to an `int*` when you assign it to `p1` which is an `int*`.

After that, you subtract one from each, so `p - 1` goes back one `int` and points to `a[0]`, while `p1 - 1` also goes back one `int`, but from a starting point of `a[5]`, so it points to `a[4]`. Thus, dereferencing `p - 1` gets you the first element in the array, while dereferencing `p1 - 1` gets the last.

Comment: There is no "degrading" or implicit conversion from `int(*)[5]` to `int *`. It's a constraint violation. Also, `&a + 1` points to a block of 5 ints that starts where `a[5]` starts (or would, if those objects actually existed)

Comment: @M.M: Agreed on it pointing to a block that begins at `a[5]` (I was going to edit it in, but there were so many qualifications already that I decided to leave it as a slight imprecision). I'm not 100% on implicit pointer conversion rules, but I'll accept it's probably bad code, just bad code that the compiler apparently allows in the OP's case (hopefully warning about it).

Comment: Compilers tend to report "warning" for this particular constraint violation and then behave as if a cast had been inserted  (the standard only requires a diagnostic, it doesn't specify grades of diagnostic)